# Django app cannot be accesed remotely with Apache+mod_wsgi

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have the following problem:

- I cannot remotely access my django app with Apache+mod_wsgi.

But I can remotely access my django app with the django development server with `manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`. And I can locally access my django app with Apache+mod_wsgi on my local computer trough port 80.

So I would like to know why I cannot access remotely trough Apache.

This is my httpd.conf (I have just posted what I modified, everything else is as default.)

```
    Listen *:80

    LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

    <IfModule ssl_module>
    SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
    SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
    </IfModule>


    WSGIScriptAlias / C:/Users/Ricardo/Dropbox/django_scada/django_scada/apache/wsgi.py
    WSGIPythonPath C:/Users/Ricardo/Dropbox/django_scada

    Alias /static/ C:/Users/Ricardo/Dropbox/static/


    <Directory C:/Users/Ricardo/Dropbox/static/>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    </Directory>



    <Directory C:/Users/Ricardo/Dropbox/django_scada/django_scada/apache>
    <Files wsgi.py>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    </Files>
    </Directory>
```

I have never configured an Apache server so I am not sure what the problem is. I think the Apache+mod_wsgi integreation works fine because I do not have any problem with the local access, so it must be something about the configuration to remotely acccess Apache. When I try to access from another computer, nothing appears on the access log, however it does when locally.

Which steps should I follow to solve my problems?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So actually the problem was related with my router and ISP. I realized this when I set up my network on my University instead of my home.

Hope this helps everyone getting stucked.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the firewall settings? That port 80 is open to the world?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea about that. I have read sometimes that I should open this port or redirect some IP...
But why I do not have to do it when I use Django development server and I have to do it when I use Apache?